# what do we mean exactly when we say a multivariate function is $k$ times differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose $x=(x_1,...,x_s)$, and $f(x)$ is a real valued function with $x\in R^s$. I read statements like "$f(x)$ is $k$ times differentiable in $x$" in a number of places. What does this mean exactly? Does this mean all $k-$th order partial derivatives exist for $f(x)$, or $\frac{\partial^k f(x)}{\partial x^k_i}$ exists for all $i=1,...,s$? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what it means for a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ to be differentiable?

Comment: How about a function $g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$?

Comment: In both cases I mean *once* differentiable.

Comment: @Jockozee Hakkiuz Not quite sure now, it would be great if you can help me review it.

Comment: Sure. You can start by checking out [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions).